# IE8 Background Image Not Showing

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, background, background-image

I have an unordered list that uses background images. All's fine in Chrome & FF, but IE8 is presenting some issues. The background images simply don't load. How can I get them to show in IE8? Is this a background image issue?

```
<ul class="service-icons">
  <li>
    <a id="service-icon-routine" href="#">
      <span class="service-category-title">Routine Service</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Styles

```
ul.service-icons {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 860px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.service-icons li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 157px !important;
    height: 140px;
    padding: .5em !important;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

ul.service-icons li a {
    padding: 0em 0em 6.7em 0em;
    width: 102px !important;
    display: block;
    height: 15px;    
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 2.2em;
}

.service-category-title {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 120px;
    text-align: center;    
}

#service-icon-routine {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/LieBz.png');
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi Kyle, did you ever figure this out? I think it has something to do with libraries like Selectivizr. I've got the same issue, but can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Hi Jacques. Nope, never got it fixed using the same method. I ended up changing my approach and just using an image and a bunch of left floats to achieve the same look.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, i eventually figured out that my problem came from Selectivizr that doesn't support the use of full URLs in CSS (i.e. HTTP://)

Answer (score 2):

make it     -ms-border-radius: 8px;

ms for microsoft

Comment: This isn't much of an answer; care to expand upon it?

Comment: Weirdly, it fixed a similar issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is choking on the use of just `background`, as it is loading as

```
background-image: url("null");
```

Changing it to the following should fix it:

```
#service-icon-routine { 
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/LieBz.png'); 
    background-position: 0px 0px; 
}
```

Comment: Tried to change it to background-image. Same thing

Comment: Interesting. When I changed it through developer tools that way, it worked. Hmmmm.

Comment: @KyleSuss--is the css being generated dynamically through LESS or SCSS or something? Somehow, even though the file path to the _css file_ is the same between IE8 and IE9, IE8 is getting the `url("null")` while IE9 gets the correct path. That would not seem possible with a static css file, so I'm guessing it is dynamic, and further guessing that something in how that is generated is changing between IE8 and IE9. In otherwords, I don't think it is an IE8 bug, but a bug in what is generating the css.

Comment: Does it look fixed to you now? I changed it but I have to do my browser testing in a bootleg way. http://www.suss.net/certified-service/

Comment: Found this in our functions.php file:

    `array_push($assets['styles'], array(
      'handle' => 'blueprint-ie'
      ,'src' => $url . '/themes/suss/css/blueprint-24-28-12/ie.css'
      ,'deps' => array('blueprint-core')
      ,'media' => 'screen, projection'
      ,'condition' => 'lt IE 8'
      ,'enqueue' => true
    ));`

This could be the source of the issue. But what do I look for in order to get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Just to jump in on this, I had a problem with a drupal plugin setting a filter which had to be  disengaged in my main css. on the image css set the filter to :

```
filter: ;
```

That should overide it. Thought this might help

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
background:url(http://i.imgur.com/LieBz.png) no-repeat;
```

Also might help to set the height and width of the image for #service-icon-routine

Comment: Thanks for the response. Tried it & no dice :(